# A popup box on page load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am using a feature of popup box in my project. When a user come to the site a popup box apears on the top of the page hiding the rest of the content. In that popup form the user has to give a download key. if the user has the key he can go forward otherwise he cannot see anything else. When the user provide the key he goes to the main page. 
Now the problem is once the user comes to the main page after providing the key and when he clicks again on the header again the page is reloaded and again tht popup form comes. How can I prevent it to apear again if some user has already given the download key . I am using php with code igniter. My code

```
<?php if($download_key != null && !isset($_POST['popup'])){?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){  
                loadPopup();    
        });  
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

downlaod key is database column and popup is a hidden input that is set when the form is submitted on the popup box.
The form that appears on popup box is as

```
<form name="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm('<?php echo $download_key ?>')"> 
 <div style="width:530px;">
     <input style="display:none; height:25px;" id="downloadkey" name="downloadkey" type="text" />
     <input style="display:none;" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $variable['QUESTION_BUTTON']['value']?>"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: oops, that was supposed to be an answer.

Comment: Just to check - you say "when a user come to the site a popup box apears on the top of the page hiding the rest of the content" - is that a java popup? What happens if they disable java - they will see your whole page without needing a code...

Comment: yes this is a javascript if they disable javascript they cant see anything bcz every thing there is based on javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `session_start()` at the beginning of pageload

EDIT: changed a bit

```
session_start();

//check if key has already been seen:

if(isset($_SESSION['download_key']) && $_SESSION['download_key'] != null ...

// then if not check if the key is submitted

else if ( isset($_POST['popup']) ... // and other checks

   // set session variable
   $_SESSION['download_key'] = $key;

else

   // load the ask for key page
```

Comment: Within the first if-block you check if the download_key is set in the session. If it is, then load normal page. The elseif you know that the session isn't set or valid, so you check if post is set with the key then check if it's valid and set the session variable and load the page. If you hit the last else, they don't have a valid session and haven't submitted a valid key, so load a page asking for the download key.

Answer (score 0):

Set a session variable, and check to see if it's present, as it will be on subsequent pageloads, and just skip the popup etc.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if ($download_key != null && !isset($_POST['popup'])) {
       if ($_SESSION['key_ok']!=true) {  //you should check if it's set first with isset()
          echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
          echo '$(document).ready(function(){';
          echo 'loadPopup();';
          echo '});';
          echo '</script>';
       }
       if (key_is_correct) {$_SESSION['key_ok']=true}
    } 
?>
```

Comment: you mean I set the key in session when a user submit the form ?

Comment: You need some sort of identifier when the correct key is already entered and received. How you do that is up to you, you could use cookies, local storage, or whatever floats your boat, but setting a simple variable in the session should be enough, and if the session is restarted the key will have to be sent again. Exactly how and where you set the session variable depends on your code, but it will need to be set after the form has been sent, and you will have to check to see if it's set correctly before you show or don't show the popup for the key, that way it shows on first pageload.